# Convert all strings in a class to interpolated strings

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, string-interpolation

I want to convert all strings that have a variable in it, example:

`string = "Hi " + name + ", How are you?"`

to his interpolated version, refactoring all these cases in a class.

I tried several ways with visual studio and visual studio code, but no one has this function, maybe with regex i can achieve this.

Comment: Are you asking for some automated way to turn `"Hi " + name + ", How are you?"` into `$"Hi {name}, How are you?"`?

Comment: Exactly, but for all ocurrences in a class.

Comment: Weird. There's an option to apply "Convert to raw string" to everything in the document, but "Convert to interpolated string" is only available for a single instance at a time

Comment: @agmalo118   ,If Matthew Watson's answer solved your issue, you should mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visual Studio can only do this for one instance at a time, as you have probably already discovered.

However, [Resharper has a function to do this for all occurrences](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2022/02/07/improvements-and-optimizations-for-interpolated-strings-a-look-at-new-language-features-in-csharp-10/).

For the following code:

```
public static void Main()
{
    string name = "matthew";

    string s = "Hi " + name + ", How are you?";
    string t = "Hi " + name + ", How are you?";

    Console.WriteLine(s + t);
}
```

It provides something like this:

[image: Resharper refactoring options]

The options for "Method" and "Class" only appear if they are needed, so this screenshot was generated from slightly different code than shown above.

Comment: Though it doesn't support the exact requirement OP is asking for "in a class" (assuming multiple classes in the same file)

Comment: Maybe my comment is incorrect, as your linked page, shows a screenshot with a class option. https://blog.jetbrains.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/ca-to-string-interpolation.png

Comment: @RandRandom It only shows options for "Method" and "Class" if there is more than one method or class in the file to which the refactoring could be applied. I'll update my answer with a screenshot showing all the options.